# How to align HTML elements(icons) along the curve using CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, icons, alignment

Good day fellas,

Can't figure out a way to align those png icons along the curve. I'm looking for CSS or(and) Javascript solutions for this. Any ideas on how to do it?

[image: icons aligned along the curve]

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="svg-curve">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 141">
      <path class="layer-1"
        d="M0,32c9.8,2.43,22.75,5.55,38,9,16,3.62,47.89,10.63,89,18,9,1.62,47.71,8.49,112,17,29.43,3.9,82.81,10.9,153,17,85.18,7.41,149.55,9.54,196,11,114.72,3.62,201,1.55,222,1,104.73-2.73,182.88-9.34,202-11,26-2.26,87.86-8,167-19,5.39-.75,32.57-5.1,66.52-10.53,22.55-3.61,45.94-7.39,52.48-8.47,27.81-4.59,72.7-13.43,142-32h0V0H0Z" />
      <path class="layer-2"
        d="M0,95c14.71,2.7,35.31,6.28,60,10,18.28,2.75,39.79,5.58,86.06,11,26.82,3.14,61.67,7.22,103.07,11,65.61,6,115.62,8.3,153.11,10,52.28,2.36,112.79,4,180.12,4,37.5,0,96.71-.13,175.12-4,28.61-1.4,91.33-4.87,172.12-13,65-6.54,130.95-13.26,217.15-29,55.91-10.19,98.43-20.15,123.09-26,67.74-16,125.3-32.33,170.12-46.07L1242.86,64.07h0c-59.38,10.1-139.89,21.83-236.16,30-13.44,1.13-52,4.4-106.08,7-129.63,6.2-240.37,5.09-326.22,2C295.06,93,113.9,56.09,71.05,47.09c-29.73-6.24-54.26-12-71-16Z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .container {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      position:relative;
    }
    .svg-curve {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .svg-curve svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      height: 200px;
    }

    .svg-curve svg .layer-1 {
      fill: red;
    }

    .svg-curve svg .layer-2 {
      fill: blue;
    }
```

And depending on the screen size the SVG height will be changed like this:

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
      .svg-curve svg {
        height: 90px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      .svg-curve svg {
        height: 120px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 992px) {
      .svg-curve svg {
        height: 150px;
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1400px) {
      .svg-curve svg {
        height: 200px;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You need an equation that generates a curve like that, then position the icons absolutely using calculated coordinates.

Comment: How are you drawing the curve? If you have an image measure everything in relation to the image and position all the icons in % terms - that way it's responsive. But if your curve changes with viewport that's different. Include your code so far so we can see.

Comment: @AHaworth, it is an SVG file, and yeah I think it will change with the viewport.

Comment: Please show us your code including the svg. It's going to depend on how it changes.

Comment: @AHaworth just updated

Comment: Thank you. It's quite tricky because only part of the curve is shown on narrower viewports. Is this what's required? I'd assumed that the full width of the curve would be shown on all devices (though of course you'll have to go to a hamburger dropdown type menu or something on really narrow ones).

Comment: @AHaworth, Priority is large screens for now but yeah we can go with a full-width curve on all devices if it makes stuff easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the svg is shown in its entirety the whole layout can be done relative to that - the % positions of each icon being calculated in the CSS.

This snippet has the aspect ratio of the svg and the positions of each icon put in from being measured. CSS calc then produces the % distances. The sizes taper down across the width and the distance between icons is constant.

The measurements in this snippet are not absolutely accurate, just put in for this demo. You'll probably want to do them for yourself.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
    .container {
      --svgAspectRatio: calc(1440 / 141);
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      position:relative;
      width: 100vw;
      height: calc(100vw / var(--svgAspectRatio) );
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      
    }
    .svg-curve {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      line-height: 0;
      background: transparent;
    }

    .svg-curve svg {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .svg-curve svg .layer-1 {
      fill: red;
    }

    .svg-curve svg .layer-2 {
      fill: blue;
    }

    .icons {
      --measuredW: 60.96; /* the measured width of the icons picture */
      --measuredH: 10.03;
      --w: calc(100vw - 8vw);
      width: var(--w);
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .icon {
      --iconW: calc(((14 - var(--n)) / 13) * 2vw);
      width: var(--iconW);
      height: var(--iconW);
      background-color: #eeeeee; 
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      left: calc(100% * (var(--n) - 1) / 13);
      z-index: 1;
      background-size: contain;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat;
      background-image: var(--bg);
      top: calc(var(--t) / var(--measuredH) * 100%);
      }
      .icon:nth-child(1) {
      --n: 1;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 4.6;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(2) {
      --n: 2;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 5.6;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(3) {
      --n: 3;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 6.48;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(4) {
      --n: 4;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 7.2;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(5) {
      --n: 5;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 7.8;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(6) {
      --n: 6;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 8.1;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(7) {
      --n: 7;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 8.1;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(8) {
      --n: 8;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 8.1;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(9) {
      --n: 9;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 7.8;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(10) {
      --n: 10;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 7.3;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(11) {
      --n: 11;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 6.5;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(12) {
      --n: 12;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 5.5;
      }
      .icon:nth-child(13) {
      --n: 13;
      --bg: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWx67.png);
      --t: 4.5;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="svg-curve">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 141">
      <path class="layer-1"
        d="M0,32c9.8,2.43,22.75,5.55,38,9,16,3.62,47.89,10.63,89,18,9,1.62,47.71,8.49,112,17,29.43,3.9,82.81,10.9,153,17,85.18,7.41,149.55,9.54,196,11,114.72,3.62,201,1.55,222,1,104.73-2.73,182.88-9.34,202-11,26-2.26,87.86-8,167-19,5.39-.75,32.57-5.1,66.52-10.53,22.55-3.61,45.94-7.39,52.48-8.47,27.81-4.59,72.7-13.43,142-32h0V0H0Z" />
      <path class="layer-2"
        d="M0,95c14.71,2.7,35.31,6.28,60,10,18.28,2.75,39.79,5.58,86.06,11,26.82,3.14,61.67,7.22,103.07,11,65.61,6,115.62,8.3,153.11,10,52.28,2.36,112.79,4,180.12,4,37.5,0,96.71-.13,175.12-4,28.61-1.4,91.33-4.87,172.12-13,65-6.54,130.95-13.26,217.15-29,55.91-10.19,98.43-20.15,123.09-26,67.74-16,125.3-32.33,170.12-46.07L1242.86,64.07h0c-59.38,10.1-139.89,21.83-236.16,30-13.44,1.13-52,4.4-106.08,7-129.63,6.2-240.37,5.09-326.22,2C295.06,93,113.9,56.09,71.05,47.09c-29.73-6.24-54.26-12-71-16Z" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="icons">
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
  <div class="icon"></div>
</div>
</div>
```